# Flow of location

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I want to use a coroutine flow as a source of the current phone position and mark it on the map. Here what I have in my `ViewModel`:

```kotlin
private val gpsAwareLocationFlow = broadcastFlow(BroadcastTransformers.gpsReceiver)
    .flatMapConcat { locationNotifier.locationFlow() }

private val locationFlow = locationNotifier.locationFlow()

val currentPosition = //here is place for solution, I suppose 
    .asLiveData()
```

When I use `locationFlow.asLiveData`, activity receives data as long as the GPS option is on. When it's turned off stream is closed and activity doesn't react on GPS option disabled or enabled.

When I use `gpsAwareLocationFlow.asLiveData()`, activity reacts properly only after the first change of GPS option. Before the option is changed it doesn't do anything.

The first idea was to use `combine` on both flows. It turned out that as long as both work well on their own (at least as flow), after combining them, result flow doesn't receive any notifications.

```
    val resultFlow = locationFlow.combine(gpsAwareLocationFlow){ a, b-> }
```

Have anybody got any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that `combineLatest` function doesn't emit anything until both flow sources don't emit at least one value. I good way to solve this is to initialize both flows with a value but I don't know if you can do this in your code.

Comment: Ok :), i mean that I don’t know if your flows are created by a framework or by you. Let me know if it works.

Comment: You're right. When I add init value for `gpsAwareLocationFlow` everything starts to work like a charm, thanks.